# How can we detect loss of signal using DJI's N3?

Tags: dji-sdk

I have a DJI N3, that uses Futbua (SBUS)  as a remote controller (RC) and a Raspberry Pi as the CPU. I want the N3 to detect signal loss from the RC.

Is there a way to do it through software, using the DJI OSDK? Or is this done in another way?

Answer (score 1):

We have done similar thing before by using both OSDK and MSDK together with N3 and lightbridge2.  OSDK(drone side) constantly sending CSI information down by osdk-to-msdk link. if msdk(RC side) did not receive the correct pulse. then it is consider as a lost link.

After lost link, then you can opt for carry on the mission or return to base right way.